# If $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt$ then $f(6)$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow[0,\infty]$ be continuous on $[0,\infty]$
>   and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. if $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{f(t)}dt$
>   then $f(6)$ is ?

$f(0)=0$

$f'(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}\implies f'(6)=\sqrt{f(6)}\implies f'(6)^2=f(6)$

Now I am trying to find out $f'(6) $ somehow

$f'(6)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 6}\dfrac{f(x)-f(6)}{x-6}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 6}\dfrac{f(x)-f'(6)^2}{x-6}$

$f'(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$

I am missing something and I am not able to solve this problem by above steps.
 Any hint?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. Is the integrand $\sqrt{t}$ or $\sqrt{f(t)}$?

Comment: @alex.jordan my bad

Comment: Without more details, $f$ could be any function of the form $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & 0\leq  x \leq x_0\\ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4}& x > x_0\end{cases}$$ for any fixed $x_0 \geq 0$. This means $f(6)$ can literally be **any** value between $0$ (for $x_0\geq 6$) to $9$ (for $x_0 = 0$).

Comment: As of right now, this question had 0 downvotes.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor What do you mean ?

Comment: @Damandeep “how did I get downvote”—you didn’t.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor oh, am I suppose to edit my question and delete that? It was few hours ago I had -1 there and can you look up my recent question no one has said something about it and I am very curious about it can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f(x) > 0$.  Upon differentiation, we have $y' = \sqrt{y} $ where $y=f(x)$. We have $\int \frac{dy }{y^{1/2}} = x + C $. Thus $2 \sqrt{y} = x + C $ And $C=0$ as $f(0)=0$. Thus, $y = \frac{x^2}{4}$. It follows that $f(6) = 9$

Added: See Clement C's comments below for a more rigorous solutions when $f(x) > 0$ is not assumed.

Comment: How do you argue that division by $\sqrt{f(x)}$? You may want to explain why $f>0$, to avoid division by $0$.

Comment: What if f(t) is identically zero.... U should deal that case too!

Comment: The diferential equation has not a uníque solution. For instance, $f(t)=0$ is also a solution. Al you can say is $0\le f(6)\le9$.

Comment: Actually, $f$ could be $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \leq x_0\\ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4}& x > x_0\end{cases}$$ for any $x_0 \geq 0$.

Comment: @clement C. Could you explain that

Comment: @CloudJR Check it: fix $x_0\geq 0$, and let $f$ be of the form above. Then $\int_0^x \sqrt{f} = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{t-x_0}{2}dt = \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4}$ for $x\geq x_0$, and $f(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{f} = 0$ for $x\leq x_0$, as required.

Comment: In my answers, it says $9$ though.

Comment: Then you either have forgotten to give us some details (is $f$ assumed $>0$ on $(0,\infty)$?), or your answer sheet is wrong. @Damandeep

Comment: To @ClementC. You confusing the OP. He is taking some basic calculus class where this types of constructions are not required. Im fact, you only explained why it works but not how you cook it. You gotta explain how you cook stuff sometimes, especially to beginners

Comment: @JimmySabater The answer $9$ is wrong -- it can equally be $0$, or 7.98$. I am sorry, but your "proof" is incorrect, and "confusing the OP" by telling him not to divide by zero seems a rather good endeavor.

Comment: My comment was not about my answer which is wrong to you. I was just commenting that f(x) you made in the comments which is confusing the OP

Comment: As for how I "cooked' this up: you can only divide by $\sqrt{f(x)}$ when $f(x)>0$. Suppose $f=0$ on $[0,x_0]$, and $f>0$ on $(x_0,\infty)$ (recall that $f'=\sqrt{f}\geq 0$, so $f$ is non-decreasing. Then for $x> x_0$, $$\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}} = 1/2$$ and **then** you can use your argument; but on $[x_0,\infty)$, not $[0,\infty)$. Then, one can check all the functions obtained this way satisfy the OP's conditions.

Comment: Its fine you two can have discussion don't worry about my confusion I am learning things and http://prntscr.com/mcdbzo

Comment: @JimmySabater Can you add a few more steps to show me how did we get $x+c$ after integration.

Comment: Notice that$\int dx = x + C $

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $f(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0,\infty)$. Then, $f$ is the integral of a non-negative function from $0$ to $x$, so this forces $f(y) = 0$ for all $y \leq x$.

On the contrary, $f$ being the integral of a non-negative function is increasing. Therefore, if $x^* = \inf\{y : f(y) = 0\}$, then $f$ is positive beyond $x^*$ and zero before (and including) that point.

---

KEY POINT : Once $f$ is shown to be positive, so is the square root, and therefore the derivative exists since we may divide by $\sqrt f$.

Since $f' = \sqrt f$, $f'$ is differentiable in $(x^*,\infty)$ (and positive on this interval, since we are considering the positive square root), with $f'' = (\sqrt f)' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt f} \times f' = \frac 12$ everywhere on $(x^*,\infty)$. Note that $f''(x^*) = 0$, from the fact that $f'$ is zero on $[0,x^*]$.

Thus, $f''$ is constant on $(x^*,\infty)$ and equal to $\frac 12$.We may solve this equation and obtain $f''$ as some quadratic on this interval, since $f '' = \frac 12 \implies f = \frac{x^2}{4} + c_1x+c_2$, with the conditions at $x^*$. You can find what $c_1,c_2$ are.

Thus, if $f$ is as above, then we may characterize $f$ as being $0$ up till some $x^*$ and then the quadratic we obtained above. In particular, $f(6)$ does not take one svalue, but a range of values depending on which $f$ we are referring to. I am sure you will be able to deduce the exact range of values it lies in from here.

---

For completeness, I add the solution : For any $x^*$, the function $f_{x^*}(x) = \mathbf 1_{x > x^*} \frac{(x-x^*)^2}{4}$ satisfies the given conditions. Conversely, any function satisfying the given conditions must be of this form.

From here, one sees that $f(6)$ may take any of the values $\mathbf 1_{6 > x^*} \frac{(6-x^*)^2}{4}$, from where the decreasing nature of this function in $x^*$ gives the answer as $f(6) \in [0,9]$. Note that if $x^* = 0$ then $f(6) = 9$,  which is the "standard" answer under the common mistake of not realizing that $f$ needs to be positive for $\sqrt f$ to be invertible.

Comment: This answer is quite sophisticated for the level of the OP. Just to point out something that the OP may have not seen, the notation ${\bf 1_A}$. Also, given that the OP asked a question is single variable calculus, he definitely not seen infimum or supremums, etc, etc

Comment: True. If the OP would like, I can expand on these notions. However, for a complete answer we must delve into these notions.

Comment: I like the answer and I give +1 to this answer, but I doubt it will help the OP. But, anyway, it will help other people see a complete rigorous solution and that also matters.

Comment: Given that your answer has been accepted (and I have up voted it as well!) I suppose your answer is the most useful to the OP, which makes good sense as well, since despite being incomplete it captures the main(intended) point.

Comment: Thank you for writing a correct answer to the question.

Comment: @ClementC you are welcome! I felt it was needed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method (the case $f=0$ is trivial; see @ClementC’s comment for slight variations of this answer where $f>0$ isn’t assumed for $x>0$):

You already know $f’(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$. Since the composition of differentials functions is differentiable (this is where we use the fact that $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$), we deduce that $f’’(x)=\frac12$. Integrating once, we get $f’(x)=\frac{x}{2}+C$, and using the fact that $f(0)=0$, we can see that $f’(0)=0$, meaning $C=0$. Integrating once more and using the initial value, we have $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}.$$

Comment: @ClementC. sir you should write an answer explaining all the things.

Comment: @Damandeep There is already [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3087982/75808) doing it.

Comment: @Daman: I am in agreement.

Comment: @Clayton yes. in view of your latest edit, I'm removing my comments not to distract from your answer. (To be clear, I didn't care at all about credit! Just so that people seeing this question in the future can have a full correct answer (which, e.g., the currently accepted answer is *not*)